# data table conflict with require-jquery.js

Tags: jquery, datatable, requirejs

Current application some one has used require-jquery.js. Now I have implemented jQuery data table. It is working fine when remove "require-jquery.js". But when I include require-jquery.js I am getting the error below:

> Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ( $ ) {

See the structure:

1. jquery.min.js
2. require-jquery.js
3. jquery.dataTables.js

And this:

```
tickerdashboardtable = $('#tickerdashboardtable').dataTable( {} );
```

I don't know how to use require-jquery.js. How can resolve this issue.

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch

Comment: Can you show some code? Where are you defining `require-jquery.js`?

Comment: structure is,
1.jquery.min.js
2.require-jquery.js
3.jquery.dataTables.js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 tickerdashboardtable = $('#tickerdashboardtable').dataTable( {} )
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Create a main.js that contains something similar to:

```
require(["jquery", "jquery.alpha", "jquery.beta"], function($) {
    //the jquery.alpha.js and jquery.beta.js plugins have been loaded.
    $(function() {
        $('body').alpha().beta();
    });
});
```

You have to call any scripts that use "define()" from the require-jquery API.

http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html